# Should I first train_test_split and then use cross validation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

If I plan to use cross validation (KFold), should I still split the dataset into training and test data and perform my training (including cross valid) only on the training set? Or will CV do everything for me? E.g.

Option 1

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y)
clf = GridSearchCV(... cv=5) 
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Option 2

```
clf = GridSearchCV(... cv=5) 
clf.fit(X y)
```

Comment: CV will do everything for you. Just specify parameters that are needed for cv. For reference [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn-model-selection-gridsearchcv) and [KFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold) which is used in CV of GridSearchCV

Comment: @SandeepKadapa although the model *will* do that for you. This is bad practice as cross-validation under estimates the model error, as you optimising parameters to minimise error at the same time. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224287/cross-validation-misuse-reporting-performance-for-the-best-hyperparameter-value/224290#224290) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CV is good, but it's better to have train/test split to provide independent score estimation on the untouched data.
If your CV and test data shows about the same score, then you can drop train/test split phase and CV on whole data to achieve slightly better model score. But don't do it before you sure your split and CV score is consistent.